# How to add a number at the end of beginning of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to an update the "s" array with a function to be ordered from minor to major. But even though the if statement is true at the end of the loop ( 2 < 7 = true) it does not add the number at the beginning but at the end. Any advice?

```js
const s = [5, 7, 2];

function editInPlace() {
  var newS = []
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (console.log(s[i] < newS[i - 1])) {
      newsS.unshift(s[i])
      console.log("Evalute to true then add at the begining: " + newS.splice(s[i]));
    } else {
      newS.push(s[i]);
      console.log("newS es: " + newS)
    }
  }
}
editInPlace();
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(anything)` returns `undefined`, so `console.log(s[i] < newS[i - 1])` is always falsy, you should move it out of the `if` condition.

```js
const s = [5, 7, 2];

function editInPlace() {
  var newS = []
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    console.log(s[i] < newS[i - 1]);
    if (s[i] < newS[i - 1]) {
      newS.unshift(s[i])
      console.log("Evalute to true then add at the begining: " + newS.splice(s[i]));
    } else {
      newS.push(s[i]);
      console.log("newS es: " + newS)
    }
  }
}
editInPlace();
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!

I completed the code in the following way:

const s = [5, 7, 2];
function editInPlace() {
  var newS = []
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] < newS[i - 1]) {
      newS.unshift(s[i])
    } else {
      newS.push(s[i]);
    }
  }
  for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
    console.log(i)
    s[i] = newS[i];
    console.log(s)
  }
}
editInPlace();

Comment: @MauricioMoradmau Glad that's helpful.